# Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

While running the swift app on Simulator, I am getting this particular error
"Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

I was looking previous response to the same problem, but nothing worked out as those were way too old.

please guide

Comment: What's your code? You probably never set a root VC at launchtime

Answer (score 0):

try setting an initial view controller. Select the view you want to present first, and in your attributes inspector, check 'is initial View Controller'